# Directory is empty but laravel does not erase it, throwing the error that "It is not empty"

Tags: php, laravel, directory, rmdir

I'm trying to delete a lot of directories that are already empty with a specific condition:

```
$noticias = Noticia::where('id_idioma', '2')->get();

    foreach($noticias as $noticia){

        $id = $noticia->id;
        $dirPath='images/noticias/'.$id.'/';
        rmdir($dirPath);

    }
```

This give me the error:
**ErrorException: rmdir(images/noticias/10446/): Directory not empty**
But Directory is EMPTY, any idea? I have also tried removing the last "/" in $dirPath.

Comment: You've probably got hidden files. (I.e., file names that begin with a dot.)

Comment: No, there is not hidden files. Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have mounted a local server on a mac with MAMP Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved using `File::deletedirectory($dirPath)` instead `rmdir($dirPath)` so:

```
$noticias = Noticia::where('id_idioma', '2')->get();

foreach($noticias as $noticia){

    $id = $noticia->id;
    $dirPath='images/noticias/'.$id.'/';
    File::deletedirectory($dirPath);

}
```

Don´t forget to add: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`